# html different content for different browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

I have an app that doesn't work well with the new version of Chrome, so I want it to show an html page asking the users to access with other browser while fixing it.

How can I make it so it knows what to show if accessing from Chrome?

Comment: unclear, I didn't understand the question... do you mean, you want browser detection ? (this last thing, I know how to do it, if you need that, tell me...)

Comment: That's what I need, if you could tell me I'll be really grateful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little plugin, called **bowser.js**

Here is the code of bowser.js: [bowser.js](https://github.com/ded/bowser/blob/master/src/bowser.js)

Just add the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bowser.js"></script>
```

And then in your JavaScript code:

```
if (bowser.msie) { 
//for internet explorer
}
else {
//for others browsers
}
```

**Note:** You can check for most browser, and versions of those....

Comment: How would it be to detect Chrome instead of IE?

Comment: `chrome`
You can check the source, it's quite simple. @Sascuash